# ASP.NET Web Forms DropDownList has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: asp.net, webforms

First of all there has been questions ( [DropDownList has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869150/dropdownlist-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exist-in-th) , [DropDownList "has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704651/dropdownlist-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exist-in-t) , [asp:DropDownList Error: 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612/aspdropdownlist-error-dropdownlist1-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-beca) ) about this and there are proposed workarounds but my question is really WHY this happens. What is more I am not satisfied with the suggested workarounds and I find them quite ugly.

So there is a page with a drop down list and a button:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWebApplication.WebForm2" ViewStateMode="Disabled" %>

<html lang="en" >
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button Text="Test" ID="btnTest" runat="server" onclick="btnTest_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I bind ddlTest with some items on Page_Init and then in btnTest_Click I bind again:

```
using System;

namespace TestWebApplication
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //SelectedIndex is -1, SelectedValue is "", SelectedItem is null
            ddlTest.DataSource = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            ddlTest.DataBind();
            ddlTest.SelectedValue = "3";
        }

        protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //SelectedIndex is 2, SelectedValue is "3", SelectedItem is {3}
            ddlTest.ClearSelection();
            //SelectedIndex is 0, SelectedValue is "1", SelectedItem is {1}
            ddlTest.SelectedIndex = -1; //Nothing changes including SelectedIndex
            ddlTest.SelectedValue = ""; //Nothing changes including SelectedValue
            ddlTest.Items.Clear();
            //SelectedIndex is -1, SelectedValue is "", SelectedItem is null
            ddlTest.DataSource = null; //Nothing changes except for the DataSource property
            ddlTest.DataSource = new[] { 1, 2 };
            ddlTest.DataBind();//Exception!
            //'ddlTest' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
            //Parameter name: value
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I get the exception. I tried different versions of these and none of them works. I tried using only ClearSelection but still got the same exception. Is this bug in the control or something I miss. Are the ugly workarounds from the other questions the only solution?

Note - the bug is reproduceable even if the button is removed and the all the code is moved in a single event handler. Just bind once set selected value and bind again.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are seeing but I don't get why you are taking this approach. First off, I would create a separate method to initialize the control. Then I would call this method from `Page_Load` if `!IsPostBack`. Then I would again call this same method from your button click handler *after* any changes has been made. Is there any reason why you're using the `Page_Init` event?

Comment: @J. Wood +1 for recommending the Page_Load, instead of the Page_Init. The Page life cycle can be really frustrating, best to avoid mucking around in its depths if possible.

Comment: It could be he was trying to avoid dirtying the ddl's viewstate...he's obviously not trying to accomplish anything here, this is just an exercise to demonstrate the error condition.

Comment: I use the Page_Init in order to avoid overriding the postback information from the DropDownList (I have ViewState disabled as stated in the page directive). The real world example is a button Delete that Deletes the selected value from the list and rebinds it. I could of course just remove it or set the value to something else in this case but there may be more complicated cases where removing is harder (what if I had to remove several related items). @Jonathan Wood in the real world code I do have a method that I call in both places.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've submitted a bug on Connect for the issue. It was resolved as "Won't fix" which in my mind means it is in fact a bug. A workaround was provided:

```
ddlTest.Items.Clear();
ddlTest.SelectedValue = null;
```

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/666808/asp-net-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-is-persisted-which-results-in-exception-if-the-control-is-databound-second-time

I kind of consider this the answer.

Comment: Awesome. 2 hours of googling and debugging...and then I find this. I had already tried setting the selectedindex to -1, setting .AppendDataBoundItems to true, and doing the binding before I put my items in. None of those approaches worked. This did!

Comment: I confirm this is the only answer that works. I tried SelectedIndex=-1 and it didnt work. I wonder WHY really because SelectedValue = null SelectedIndex=-1, ClearSelection() and Item.Selected = false should all be synonyms. My app is migrating from NET11 to NET4. In NET11, this error did not happen.

Answer (score 3):

> **Why do I get the exception.**

After Page_Init() is called, ddlTest has been bound to 3 items: "1", "2" and "3".  You then set the SelectedValue to "3" and manipulate all sorts of things related to the DropDownList control.  **But the control is still bound to the previous list** -- you haven't called .DataBind() again even though you've changed the DropDownList properties.  The exception occurs because the control is still bound to the {1, 2, 3}, it's hanging on to the previous .SelectedValue and you've just tried to .DataBind() it to a list that does not include "3".

Comment: So how do I bind to a list that doesn't include 3 if I cannot change the SelectedValue property? It seems like Catch 22.

Comment: You can indeed change it, but you need to do all of the changing before your first call to .DataBind().  I had this same problem where I was changing the .SelectedValue in a couple of places (erroneously).  Make just one call after .DataBind() and you should be golden. +1 for Joseph Heller.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by adding a DataBinding method.

```
protected void myDDL_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myDDL.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        myDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

On design page...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDDL" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" OnDataBinding="myDDL_DataBinding"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="myDDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) As written, your example actually throws an exception on `ddlTest.SelectedValue = "";`, since there is no item in the collection with a `Value` of "".  I think this would be expected under any circumstance.

2) I get an exception every time I try to set the `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex` of the DDL to something that WILL BE invalid by the time the DDL is rendered.  But the exception doesn't happen until the `DropDownList.Items` collection is actually changed, for instance with a `DropDownList.Databind()`.  The first thing I did was make this change to Page_Init:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SelectedIndex is -1, SelectedValue is "", SelectedItem is null
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlTest.DataSource = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        ddlTest.DataBind();
        ddlTest.SelectedValue = "3";
    }
}
```

Now what gets interesting is this first example throws an exception, but the second one doesn't.  They both set a `SelectedValue` that is valid at the time, but the value in the first example ("3") will not be valid by the time the page renders:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SelectedIndex is 2, SelectedValue is "3", SelectedItem is {3}
    ddlTest.SelectedValue = "3"; 
    //SelectedIndex is 2, SelectedValue is "3", SelectedItem is {3}
    ddlTest.ClearSelection();
    //SelectedIndex is 0, SelectedValue is "1", SelectedItem is {1}
    ddlTest.Items.Clear();
    //SelectedIndex is -1, SelectedValue is "", SelectedItem is null
    ddlTest.DataSource = null;
    ddlTest.DataSource = new[] { 1, 2 };
    ddlTest.DataBind(); //Exception!
    //'ddlTest' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
    //Parameter name: value
}

protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SelectedIndex is 2, SelectedValue is "3", SelectedItem is {3} (from viewstate)
    ddlTest.SelectedValue = "2"; 
    //SelectedIndex is 1, SelectedValue is "2", SelectedItem is {3}
    ddlTest.ClearSelection();
    //SelectedIndex is 0, SelectedValue is "1", SelectedItem is {1}
    ddlTest.Items.Clear();
    //SelectedIndex is -1, SelectedValue is "", SelectedItem is null
    ddlTest.DataSource = null;
    ddlTest.DataSource = new[] { 1, 2 };
    ddlTest.DataBind(); //No Exception...
}
```

So, what conclusion can we draw from this?  Well it seems the problem is due to setting the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedValue` property of the DDL before the contents of the DDL may be changed on the same page cycle.  If the previously set value is still available in the new contents of `DropDownList.Items`, you're in business.  But if it's not in there, you get an exception.

My guess is this has something to do with thread-safeness but I'm no expert on that so hopefully someone can comment.

Comment: Strange that it throws exception on another row for you. What version of ASP.NET are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had `DropdownList` in `templatedfield` of `gridview`. Now `datasource` of grid had `employeeid`  item. I have this in stored proceedure, `isnull(employeeid,0)` for datasource and guess what `DropdownList`does not have a value of 0 on its items; so i changed that to   isnull(employeeid,1) because the first item in `DropdownList`has `employeeid =1` and this solved problem

Answer (score -2):

Because there is no any datasource when your page is reloaded (postback happened), you should add SqlDataSource control in your .aspx file even in reloading page recognize DropDownList's DataSource. Then You can use InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand and SelecCommand to obtain your DB.