# DropDownList in DetailsView-Issue - ddl has a value which is invalid because it doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

well I've stumbled upon similar cases of this problem, and also followed the solution approaches. But my case is quite strange, as I have 2 different DetailsView-controls (with different data), one works, the other doesn't.

So here's the problem in detail. I get the following error message:

```
DropDownList2 has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

I am aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886179/asp-net-web-forms-dropdownlist-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-d), and maybe I'm stupid and not seeing something. But maybe you do. I have 2 Detailsviews, which bind their data based on a dataset for one user. Both DVs have DropdownList-Controls inside their EditItemTemplates, which bind the possible values for this very column. I use SelectedValue='<%# Bind("mycolumn") %>' for my DropDownList-template exactly the same way in the 2 DVs.

As said, I am aware of code-behind workarounds, but I want to avoid those, to keep my code clean and consistent. I can't really document why I use a workaround on one DetailsView, and why I don't on the other.

Here is the code of my 2 DetailsViews:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dv_theme_ava" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"  DataKeyNames="Pat_ID">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Theme">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                    DataTextField="theme" DataValueField="theme" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("theme") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Label ID="lolbel2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("theme") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:interacct_SQL_convConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [theme] FROM [gui_themes]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Avatar">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
                    DataTextField="avatar" DataValueField="avatar">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Label ID="lolbel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("avatar") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:interacct_SQL_convConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [avatar] FROM [gui_avatars]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:interacct_SQL_convConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [pat_gui_config] WHERE ([Pat_ID] = @Pat_ID)" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [pat_gui_config] WHERE [Pat_ID] = @Pat_ID"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [pat_gui_config] ([Pat_ID], [theme], [avatar]) VALUES (@Pat_ID, @theme, @avatar)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [pat_gui_config] SET [theme] = @theme, [avatar] = @avatar WHERE [Pat_ID] = @Pat_ID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Pat_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Pat_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="theme" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="avatar" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="Pat_ID" SessionField="sel_pat_id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="theme" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="avatar" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Pat_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:DetailsView ID="dv_treat_edit" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Tr_ID" DataSourceID="sql_newcat" DefaultMode="Edit"
    Height="50px" Width="90%" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="dv_details" Style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tr_ID" HeaderText="Tr_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="Tr_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="syn_ger" HeaderText="Display Name (German)" SortExpression="syn_ger" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_type0" runat="server" DataSourceID="sql_ddl_type0" DataTextField="type"
                    DataValueField="type" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("type") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql_ddl_type0" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:interacct_SQL_convConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [type] FROM [entry_type]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exclusive for Patient_ID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_excl_pat0" runat="server" DataSourceID="sql_ddl_exclpat0"
                    DataTextField="Pat_ID" DataValueField="Pat_ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("custom_cat_for_Pat") %>'
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql_ddl_exclpat0" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:interacct_SQL_convConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [Pat_ID] FROM [patients]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
    <CommandRowStyle CssClass="dv_footer" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="dv_tr" />
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="Top" Visible="False" />
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql_newcat" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:interacct_SQL_convConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [treat_cat]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [treat_cat] WHERE [Tr_ID] = @Tr_ID"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [treat_cat] ([description], [syn_ger], [type], [custom_cat_for_Pat]) VALUES (@description, @syn_ger, @type, @custom_cat_for_Pat)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [treat_cat] SET [description] = @description, [syn_ger] = @syn_ger, [type] = @type, [custom_cat_for_Pat] = @custom_cat_for_Pat WHERE [Tr_ID] = @Tr_ID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Tr_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="syn_ger" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="custom_cat_for_Pat" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="syn_ger" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="custom_cat_for_Pat" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Tr_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Note: the data model is quite simple. For comparison I used the 2 fields "theme" and "type". Both tables only have 1 column in my database, holding string entries.

Now, the "type"-DDL gets it's items perfectly fine, and has the SelectedValue bound to the value brought to the DetailsView by the datasource. When I bind the "theme"-DDL with SelectedValue, I get the error. Interesting: in the same EditItemTemplate I have set up a Label (ID "lolbel2" :p) to check the databinding. It works (of course, when I remove the SelectedValue from the DDL). So without the SelectedValue in the DDL my output is like
[DROPDOWNLIST] with items "space", "magic"
[LABEL] with text "magic" (since this is the value of my test-user).

Am I missing something? Am I completely nuts?
So, sorry for re-asking this question for like the 10th-time, but I want to UNDERSTAND what my code does.

Thanks in advance!
Konrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooooohkay. Found the problem, that's what you get when you are stubborn as a goat. :)

When debugging a workaround with a HiddenField I noticed that the value, which gets bound the same way as the Label-Control, has some trailing whitespace. In particular: instead of "dog" I got "dog     ". While this isn't shown in the asp:Label, I guess this was the reason why the value wasn't found in the DropDownList.

Where did the whitespace come from? In my SQL table I created the columns for "theme" and avatar as "nchar", and not "nvarchar". Apparently when using "nchar" as DataType the not-used chars of the tupels are filled with whitespace, or let's say the fields have fixed width (always x chars).

Changing the datatype to "nvarchar" helped me to get rid of the whitespace, and now the databinding of the DDLs works just fine.

I am documenting this, as maybe someone else will stumble over this aswell - and since there are 50 solutions and workarounds, maybe just taking a look at the database sometimes does the trick.